# How to make a curve with straight line

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to achieve straight line curve . so, can any one help me to achieve this without using paint

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3d3C.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple tool like [**Flutter Shape Maker**](https://fluttershapemaker.com/) by Retroportal Studios and using which I wrote the below code

I don't think it will be possible without Paint as you said, but Paint can be much easier with the tool mentioned

I have made a custom shape which looks just like yours though a little shaky but you will get the idea

```
class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    
    

  Paint paint_0 = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
     
         
    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width*0.3325000,size.height*0.2128571);
    path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.5200000,size.height*0.2139286,size.width*0.5200000,size.height*0.2139286,size.width*0.5825000,size.height*0.2142857);
    path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.6650000,size.height*0.2871429,size.width*0.6041667,size.height*0.3471429,size.width*0.5825000,size.height*0.3571429);
    path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.5200000,size.height*0.3567857,size.width*0.3933333,size.height*0.3575000,size.width*0.3325000,size.height*0.3557143);
    path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.3091667,size.height*0.3500000,size.width*0.2533333,size.height*0.2857143,size.width*0.3325000,size.height*0.2128571);
    path_0.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0);
  
    
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClipPath` for building any kind of shape without using `Paint`.

But if you also want to avoid it, you can use `Stack` to achieve something like this:

Try on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 40,
          width: 160,
          color: Colors.blueGrey
        ),
        Positioned(

          right: -40,
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.skewX(-0.6),
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 56,
              color: Colors.white,
            )

          ),
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect, you answer helped me a lot, thank you

Comment: sure, no problem